# How can I change the size of canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, cypress

This code only let me to display a rescaled canvas.

```
cy.get('#canvas').then(cnv => {
  cnv[0].style.width = '1222px';
  cnv[0].style.height = '644px';
    
})
```

In fact for example cnv[0].width returns the old width value.
If I change it the canvas will be cleaned.

Comment: _"If I change it the canvas will be cleaned."_ - That's how it is supposed to work. If you change the size you have to re-draw the content.

Comment: The general way is to have your draw function on your resize event for canvas